# Comparing and replacing elements of a list

Tags: python

I have a dictionary :-

```
   dict= { 'b' : 'bob' , 'c' : 'code' , 'd' : 'do'}
import re
def convert(str)
 data=list(str.replace(' ',''))
 for dat in data
 print dat
 # this gives an output as
 # b
 # c
 # d
 # Here I want to compare each character(b,c,d) with the key in my dict{} dictionary
 # and if there is a match(dict has 'b':'bob') then I want to replace the character with the 
 # dictionary value.
 # In summary i want to convert string bcd to bobcodedo.


if __name__== "__main__":
 sam('bcd')
```

In summary i want to convert string bcd to bobcodedo.

Answer (score 3):

Don't name your `dictionary` `dict`, `string` `str`, etc.

```
In [12]:

D={ 'b' : 'bob' , 'c' : 'code' , 'd' : 'do'}
S='bcd'
In [13]:

''.join(map(D.get,S))
Out[13]:
'bobcodedo'
```

To expand it to your second question:

```
In [15]:

''.join(map(lambda x: D.get(x, ''),'bcdefg'))
Out[15]:
'bobcodedo'
In [16]:

''.join(map(lambda x: D.get(x, x),'bcdefg'))
Out[16]:
'bobcodedoefg'
```

To answer the question in your comment:

```
In [12]:

bad_str='|xyz'
in_str1='acdefggt'
in_str2='asxsttgm'
In [13]:

set(bad_str).intersection(in_str2)
Out[13]:
{'x'}
In [14]:

if len(set(bad_str).intersection(in_str1))==0:
    print 'do someting'
else:
    print 'Abort!'
do someting
```

Comment: Thanks !! But this does not work if I have string s='bcdefg' , Since I don't want to define e,f,g in my dictionary. How to change bcd only and keep efg as the same?

Comment: Appreciate it, Also, what if I want to throw an error when I find a character say "|" in between my string = 'bcd|efg'. In this string when I find '|' I want to throw an exception message- "Stop parsing". How can this be achieved ? Should reg ex be used here?